# Getting back error messages from Golang executable into shell script

Tags: shell, unix, go, logging

I am new to programming.

I have a golang package for moving files to s3. I'm calling it from a unix shell script (without
 nohup). Is there a way to send error messages from go code to shell script?

Comment: If golang program writes an error info into `os.Stderr` then you can capture it in shell script.

Comment: If you don't redirect the output to `/dev/null` when calling `nohup`, a `nohup.out` file will be created in the working directory. This file stores the script output. Otherwise, see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/676664/where-can-i-get-nohup-out-if-script-starts-at-startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676664/where-can-i-get-nohup-out-if-script-starts-at-startup).

Comment: Probably I misunderstood your question. Please provide more detail, or show us the shell script in question and how exactly did you execute `nohup`?.

Comment: @jeevatkm Currently Im using log to write messages to a log file. Is there a way to write to os.Stderr using log? Thank you.

Comment: @putu Apologies for the confusion. I meant to write without nohup.

Comment: @putu
Here is how Im calling :-
#! /bin/bash

moveToS3() {
 
move -i abd-123 -f filename
exit $?

}

move

-----------------
I want to echo the error messages instead of direct exit.

Comment: @Cassidy Yes, if you're Go std logger, by default log messages goes to `os.Stderr`.

Comment: Can you confirm that calling the go executable from the command line works and prints or logs an error message before attempting to run it in a bash script? Can you link us to your source code used to produce the move executable? Further, you showed an -i and a -f flag. What does the -i flag do?